# Abstract Equality Comparison - Prefix Operator

Tags: javascript

I read the [specs](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/#sec-abstract-equality-comparison) of javascript and found this snippet:

> 7.2.14 Abstract Equality Comparison
>
> 6. If Type(x) is Boolean, return the result of the comparison ! ToNumber(x) == y.

What does `!ToNumber(x)` mean?

Example:

**true == 1 equals to true**

but `!true == 1` equals to false, so it is not the negate operator.

Comment: `!ToNumber(x)` is the same as `Boolean(ToNumber(x)) !== true`. `!true == 1` is basically `false == 1`, which evaluates as `false`.

Comment: but !1 == 1 will be false because true will be converted to 1. The expression true == 1 will evaluate to true.

Comment: "but !1 == 1 will be false because true will be converted to 1." No, `!1` will become `false` then compared with `1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer in the spec while searching "!".

> Similarly, prefix ! is used to indicate that the following invocation of an abstract or syntax-directed operation will never return an abrupt completion and that the resulting Completion Record's [[Value]] field should be used in place of the return value of the operation.
>   [Source](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/#sec-returnifabrupt-shorthands)